# Add discount on each product based on product price

Tags: magento2, cart, api, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount

I have 100 products in my store and each product has different price. I want to add discount on each product based on specific price.
For example, If a product is added into the cart and it has 100usd price then i want to apply 10% discount on it and if a product is added into the cart and it has 110usd price then i want to apply 11% discount on it and so on. I hope you understand what I want to achieve.
in simple words, discount on each product based on product price.
Thanks

Comment: Hello @Asad, you can use the Cart Price Rules, For this
Marketing admin Menu -> Cart Price Rules

Comment: Hello @MohdShahbaz, I can't use cart price rules. Ihave to add discount again each product and this discount is based on product price. And i need to do all these when i will add product into cart through cart API.

Comment: Ok, i will post something if i found anything

Comment: Okay, That would be a great.